# Zend Framework 2 - direct to two different pages

Tags: zend-framework2

how to direct to two different pages? In login page if one login as admin(role:admin in db) direct to admin page and if he is student(role:student in db) direct to student page.

Comment: By two different pages, you mean two different modules, controllers, actions or layout?

Comment: `if(...) {...} else {...}`? What's the problem?

Comment: i mean to say two views. example: admin.phtml and student.phtml pages

Comment: By using zend_auth and zend_acl how can i implement this???

Comment: So you don't want to **redirect**, but only **render** two different views, right? Without changing the URL?

Comment: In controller i have to check whether he is admin or student using their role in db and direct to those views.

Comment: use some partial views. And check role/acl if he is admin include admin partial view else include student views

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of elements involved in your solution:

1) **authentication**.  This is where the user logs in and is (or isn’t) granted access to the system.

2) **authorization**.  This is where the user’s role is determined, which will allow the user access to specific parts of the system.

3) **module schema**.  Often in a student/administrator relationship there will be a student area and an administrator area; and the students have permission to visit the student area and the administrators have permission to visit BOTH the student area and the administrator area.  If this is your case, you will want to develop one or a group of modules dedicated to the students and one or a group of modules dedicated to the administrators; and assign permissions based on roles.

4) **styling**. It can be important to style the views for the administrator spaces differently from the student spaces so that it is clear to administrators which spaces they are in.  This can be done easily with [EdpModuleLayouts](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts).

5) **landing pages and routing**.  As @dragoste points out in the comments above, you can use a simple `IF … ELSE` statement (or a `SWITCH` statement if you increase the number of roles) to redirect users to specific landing pages following authorization. In the function that redirects users, you’ll want to use:

```
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('my-target-route');
```